# cordova.plugins.diagnostic.location enabled is not a function

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to use the plugin:

```
Cordova diagnostic plugin
```

But when I use this function:

```
cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled is not a function
```

Why I get this error?

Comment: no one, know ? :(

Comment: Need some more info here. Are you trying to access the plugin in a 'deviceready' block? All plugins must be used inside that to make sure they have loaded.